# Python equivalent of continuations with Ruby

Tags: python, ruby, continuations

What is the Python equivalent of the following code in Ruby?

```
def loop
  cont=nil
  for i in 1..4
    puts i
    callcc {|continuation| cont=continuation} if i==2
  end
  return cont
end

> c=loop
1
2
3
4
> c.call
3
4
```

Reference: [Secrets of lightweight development success, Part 9: Continuations-based frameworks](http://www-128.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/os-lightweight9/)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The article you quoted contains a link to [Continuations Made Simple And Illustrated](http://www.ps.uni-sb.de/~duchier/python/continuations.html) in the Resources section, which talks about continuations in the Python language.

Answer (score 2):

take a look at the [yield](http://www.python.org/doc/2.6/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-yield-statement) statement to make generators.

I don't speak any ruby, but it seems like you're looking for this:

```
def loop():
    for i in xrange(1,5):
        print i
        if i == 2:
            yield


for i in loop():
    print "pass"
```

Edit: I realize this is basically a specialization of real continuations, but it should be sufficient for most purposes. Use `yield` to return the continuation and the `.next()` message on the generator (returned by just calling `loop()`) to reenter.

Answer (score 2):

Using [`generator_tools`](http://www.fiber-space.de/generator_tools/doc/generator_tools.html#mozTocId557432) (to install: '`$ easy_install generator_tools`'):

```
from generator_tools import copy_generator

def _callg(generator, generator_copy=None):
    for _ in generator: # run to the end
        pass
    if generator_copy is not None:
        return lambda: _callg(copy_generator(generator_copy))

def loop(c):
    c.next() # advance to yield's expression
    return _callg(c, copy_generator(c))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    def loop_gen():
        i = 1
        while i <= 4:
            print i
            if i == 2:
                yield
            i += 1

    c = loop(loop_gen())
    print("c:", c)
    for _ in range(2):
        print("c():", c())
```

Output:

```
1
2
3
4
('c:', <function <lambda> at 0x00A9AC70>)
3
4
('c():', None)
3
4
('c():', None)
```

Comment: generator_tools is quite limited on what it can copy, see its documentation. I wouldn't nominate generator_tools to be a drop-in replacement for callcc.

Answer (score 2):

There are many weak workarounds which work in special cases (see other answers to this question), but there is no Python language construct which is equivalent to `callcc` or which can be used to build something equivalent to `callcc`.

You may want to try [Stackless Python](http://www.stackless.com/) or the [greenlet](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/greenlet) Python extension, both of which provide coroutines, based on which it is possible to build one-shot continutations, but that's still weaker than Ruby's `callcc` (which provides full continuations).

Answer (score 0):

```
def loop():    
    def f(i, cont=[None]):        
        for i in range(i, 5):
            print i
            if i == 2:
                cont[0] = lambda i=i+1: f(i)
        return cont[0]
    return f(1)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    c = loop()
    c()
```